# How do I pick a random condition from this loop to print?

Tags: python

Here is my code. It is a bot that finds keywords from a subreddit and posts a reply based on the keyword. 
It has 3 different keywords to search for, and a specific answer to each keyword. 
**But it should randomize which keyword:answer to print out. *How do I do this?*** 
Sometimes it will want to say "Hello" to 'hello' comments, other times 'Goodbye' to 'goodbye' comments and so on.

It has a sleeptime of 10 minutes between each scan.

```
import random
import time

hello_comment = "Hello"
goodbye_comment = "Goodbye"
it_is_true = "It is true"

for submission in subreddit.hot(limit=10):
    print(submission.title)

    for comment in submission.comments:
        if hasattr(comment, "body"):
            comment_lower = comment.body.lower()
            if " hello " in comment_lower:
                print(comment.body)
                comment.reply(penge_comment)
            elif " goodbye" in comment_lower:
                print(comment.body)
                comment.reply(koster_comment)
            elif " is it true? " in comment_lower:
                print(comment.body)
                comment.reply(it_is_true)
            
            time.sleep(600)
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"which keyword:answer to print out"_? Can you give some example situations and what the expected behavior would be?

Comment: put the options inside a list, then use `random.choice` to select the option you want to check

Comment: The printed out reply should be specific to the keyword. If it finds 'hello' it should print out "Hello".

Comment: If a comment contains 'hello' it should reply "Hello". If it randomizes reply given any of the keywords being there, it will just say "Goodbye" to 'hello' comments and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you can

`import random`

move your answers in a list

`answers =["hi","hello","bye"]`

change your answer to

`comment.reply(random.choice(answers))`

random.choice will pick a random answer for you.

This is what you want if you have multiple keywords:
Create a answers dict `{keyword: list[answer,]}`

```
answers = {"keyword1":["a","b"],"keyword2":["c","d"]}

for keyword in answers:
   if keyword in comment_lower:
      comment.reply(random.choice(answers[keyword]))
      break
```

Comment: But will that random answer be specific to the keyword in the comment?

Comment: well, you will have to create multiple lists for each keyword

Comment: I am new to python. Can you show me how?

Comment: yup, have a look now

Comment: Okay, will try that solution. Thanks

Comment: I tried it and it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a list with the options you want to print and choose one element randomly:

```
import random

l = ["text 1", "text 2", "text 3" ]

print(random.choice(l))
```

Comment: But then the answer will not be specific to the keyword. If a comment contains 'hello' it should reply "Hello". If it randomizes reply given any of the keywords being there, it will just say "Goodbye" to 'hello' comments and so on.

Comment: You just do a list for each condition :)